# Find the smallest $a>1$ such that $\frac{a+\sin x}{a+\sin y} \leq e^{(y-x)}$ for all $x \leq y$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Can anyone please help me with the following question:

Find the smallest $a>1$ such that $$\frac{a+\sin x}{a+\sin y} \leq e^{(y-x)}$$ for all $x \leq y$

**My attempt:**

I think we should rearrange to get $a$. So I multiply both sides by $a+\sin y$ which is always positive since $a>1$, we get

$$a(1- e^{(y-x)}) \leq (\sin y)(e^{(y-x)}) - \sin x$$
we can divide by $1 - e^{(y-x)}$ because $x \leq y$, now we get

$$a \geq  \frac{(\sin y)(e^y) - (\sin x)(e^x)} {e^x - e^y}$$
so we have a necessary and sufficient condition.

I think we need to maximise the right hand side to find the answer, but I don't know how! This is from a undergraduate admission test (Trinity College Cambridge) so we can use only high school mathematics.

Comment: Something in your answer seems off. Look at $x=-\frac{\pi}{2},y=\pi$. then your minimal a  will be $a=\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{\pi}}<0<1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $b = e^x$ and $c = e^y$. Then the problem is to find the supremum of all numbers of the form $f(c) - f(b)/(c-b)$ for $c > b > 0$, where $f(t) = - t \sin \log t$.

By the mean value theorem, such numbers are always of the form $f'(d)$. Conversely, any value $f'(d)$ of the derivative is itself the limit of numbers of the given form.

So the problem amounts to finding the supremum of $f'(t) = -\sin \log t - \cos \log t$ for $t > 0$. That means the maximum value of $-\cos x - \sin x = - \sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4)$ for all $x$.

Therefore take $a = \sqrt{2}$.

EDIT: A comment questioned the use of the mean value theorem. An alternative is to prove the following lemma: If $f'(t) \leq M$ for all $t$, then $(f(c) - f(b))/(c-b) \leq M$, which can fulfill the same purpose in this problem. This can be proved using only the fact that a function with nonnegative derivative is increasing (i.e., nondecreasing).

Comment: That is a great solution, but the OP wants a solution in high school level, do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Isn't the mean value theorem actually taught in (some of the) British secondary schools? (I'm not from the UK, but seem to remember that historically at least some of the more famous public schools provided top-notch math education.)

Comment: @DiegoMath Sorry, I don't know a more elementary solution than this one. For a question of this difficulty, I thought it would be relatively safe to presume that the mean-value theorem was known. I'm not sure how to check what the math curriculum is at A-levels in England.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x+t \implies t\ge 0 \iff a\ge \dfrac{\sin{x}-e^t\sin{(x+t)}}{e^t-1}=\dfrac{\sin{x}-e^t\sin{x}\cos{t}-e^t\sin{t}\cos{x}}{e^t-1}=\dfrac{(1-e^t\cos{t})\sin{x}-e^t\sin{t}\cos{x}}{e^t-1}=A(t)\sin{(x-g(t))}$

$g(t)=\arcsin{\dfrac{e^t\sin{t}}{\sqrt{(1-e^t\cos{t}))^2+(e^t\sin{t})^2}}} , \sin{(x-g(t))} \le 1 $

$A(t)=\dfrac{\sqrt{(1-e^t\cos{t}))^2+(e^t\sin{t})^2}}{e^t-1}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-2\cos{t}e^t+e^{2t}}{(e^t-1)^2}}$

now $a\ge A_{max}(t)$ means to find max of $f(t)=\dfrac{1-2\cos{t}e^t+e^{2t}}{(e^t-1)^2}$

$f(t)=1+\dfrac{2e^t(1-\cos{t})}{(e^t-1)^2}=1+\dfrac{4e^t\sin^2{\dfrac{t}{2}}}{(e^t-1)^2}\le 1+\dfrac{4\sin^2{\dfrac{t}{2}}}{t^2} \le 2 \iff \dfrac{\sin{\frac{t}{2}}}{\frac{t}{2}} \le 1 \cap \dfrac{(e^t-1)^2}{e^t} \ge t^2$

$\dfrac{(e^t-1)^2}{e^t} \ge t^2 \iff h(t)=e^{2t}+1-2e^t-t^2e^t \ge 0 \iff h'(t) \ge 0\cap h(0)=0 \iff h'(t)=2e^t(e^t-t-1) \ge0 \iff e^t \ge t+1$

the last one is trivial or one can do $k(t)=e^t-t-1\ge 0 \iff k'(t)= e^t-1 \ge 0 \cap k(0)=0 $

so $a \ge \sqrt{2}$ and "=" will hold when $t \to 0^+\cap x-g(t)=2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2} $